# Set key value of @ForeignKey in "sequelize-typescript'

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to figure out how to set the value of the key (to not be inferred from the Model. of the `@ForeignKey(()=> *MyModel*)`

```
import { AllowNull, Column, ForeignKey, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript'
import ModelA from './ModelA'

@Table
class ModelB extends Model<ModelB>  {
  
  // VVV The key should be modela_id and not easier
  @ForeignKey(()=> ModelA)
  @Column
  @AllowNull(false)
  harder!: number
  
  // VVV The key should be modela_id and not easier
  @ForeignKey(()=> ModelA)
  @Column
  @AllowNull(false)
  easier!: number
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!